# Is there a faster way to get Potions of Steeling?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

I am already at level 5 and so far I have encountered only one. I obviously don't have the Alchemist tree so I won't be able to craft one to save my life. Right now I have like 20 each of Iron and Steel Ingots and am planning to create a couple of the Royal Beatdowns and some Rings of Iron Thorns.

I was thinking of increasing my chances via the RotDG's Vendor Machine room in which you can create a Vendor Machine for yourself. I usually go Growth, Pillar, and Scrutiny to produce a Crafting Vendor. I guess my question is, should I be going with the drink vendor? Or some other Vendor? And is there ANY other way to obtain it?

Comment: "Steal" them? Sorry, bad pun but it's early...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure you've found the answer yourself since then, but just in case: no, if you are not an Alchemist, you have to hope for it to appear on the ground or in a store. You should stick to Food or Craft vendors if you don't have any use for the mana gained from a Drink machine.

Speaking of mana, if you're not yet maintaining Szygy, you might want to raid existing Drink machines on the floors you've explored. A [Gargle Blaster](http://www.dredmorwiki.com/wiki/Pan-Galactic_Gargle_Blaster) is never a bad find.